# Как понять логику пользователя при работе с вашим продуктом?

Tags: android, firebase, update

Этот вопрос носит частично *философский* и частично *прикладной* характер, так что не обессудьте :) Я думаю большинство из нас имеет или планирует иметь у себя в практике опубликованные продукты собственного производства. Имеется в виду все что можно написать будь то бэкенд для чего либо или сайт, приложение для мобильного устройства или десктопное решение. Так как я в основном (можно посмотреть на преобладание этой тематики в моих вопросах-ответах здесь) занимаюсь мобильной разработкой под Android, то я буду в своих суждениях находится рядом с этой отраслью, но каждый из нас сможет интерпретировать мои рассуждения на область своих работ.

Так вот, возьмем ситуацию, что программист (например я) пилит свое приложение (программу). Пилит долго и усердно, выявляя в процессе триллионы багов и косяков. **Баги чинятся, костыли придумываются.** И вот вы доходите до того чтобы выпустить свое творение в свет, пока только для внутренних тестов. Например в Google Play Console есть такая штука как закрытое тестирование. Все выложено и вы ждете фидбека. В процессе написания программы, например я подключал разные решения для отлова ошибок: вначале был `Fabric.io` а после того как проект перешел под крыло `Firebase` то подключил `Firebase`. Я думаю большинство знает о прелестях данного сервиса, но тем не менее я позволю себе еще раз написать что данный сервис подключается к проекту и позволяет получать данные об ошибках которые возникают в процессе работы вашего приложения. Данный сервис подключен и все работает стабильно. Вы получаете ошибку, фиксите ее и выкладываете апдейт. Казалось бы схема проста и понятно, если бы не одно но. В процессе тестирования каждый человек ведет себя по-разному и соответственно действует тоже не всегда одинаково. И я думаю бывали у каждого случаи, когда приложение крашится, вы получаете ошибку, но в процессе вашего тестирования все в **этом** месте было в порядке. А теперь собственно к сути вопроса - как понять что именно творит пользователь что приложение стабильно падает. Ведь образ мышления программиста и юзера отличается (не в обиду юзерам). Да можно действовать прямолинейно - прилетел баг, починил выложил. Но что если вы чините, как вам кажется правильно а оно не чинится в итоге. Как поймать те самые условия когда пользователь получает ошибку? Может есть какие-то решения данной проблемы?

**Пусть каждого из нас минуют баги и сопровождает только правильный код :)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что касается вылетов - тут просто фиксить и фиксить, фиксить уже пофикшенное и пофикшенное дважды и трижды... Если пользователи как-то не по вашей логике что-то нажимают и приложение вылетает с ошибкой, то, тут виноваты только вы и решение одно - фиксы. Приложение не должно вылетать, чтобы пользователь не делал и не нажимал в приложении (не беру в расчёт аппаратные проблемы и различия в прошивках).

Как отследить, что делал пользователь до вылета? Используйте события (например, в том же фаербейсе). Покройте приложения событиями (по сути логом), в итоге вы получите отличную статистику саму по себе, а в случае падения сможете проследить цепочку действий пользователя.

*Немного не по теме, но вопрос, как мне показалось, интересный :)*

> Как понять логику пользователя при работе с вашим продуктом?

Ответ простой: никак!

Но вы можете предположить как будут действовать пользователи с приложением и в приложении. И поможет в этом опыт (свой или чужой (последнее в большинстве случаем за деньги)). Нет, это не опыт разработки и не опыт пользования вашей программой вами же самими, притворившись глупым, действующим совершенно не логически, пользователем (не получится, я пробовал). Это какое-то понимание того, что нужно пользователям (именно множеству), как они будут действовать и что видеть в программе (их видение сильно отличается от того, что видим мы - разработчики (например, мы смотрим на картинку и видим одно, они же видят совершенно другое, причём кол-во вариантов этого самого "другого" огромное и не поддаётся объяснению)).

Где же взять этот самый опыт? Тут вам на помощь придёт главным образом взаимодействие с пользователями. Всяческие отзывы от них, обратная связь (когда они пишут вам на почту гневные письма, мол "это штука работает не так как я думал"), разного рода анкеты (встречается довольно редко, но позволяет весьма неплохо определить что нужно пользователям, что нравится, что не так и т.п.) и всё т.п.

Ещё неплохой вариант, собрать знакомых, никак не связанных с программированием и не очень разбирающихся в компах/смартфонах (зависит от целевой аудитории программы). Дать им вашу программу "попользовать". Вы же в это время наблюдайте за ними, что им будет не понятно и т.п. Можете да же записывать себе, делать пометки. Но не подсказывайте им, иначе эксперимент будет не удачным. И помните, обычный пользователь - если что-то не понимает, то в следующую минуту с огромной вероятностью закроет и удалит приложение.